# Quality Center: Set a Step Field in Python

Tags: python, hp-quality-center

I have a very simple problem here. 
I want to achieve the following VB script Code in Python:-

```
dim objSfact 
dim objOrun 
dim mystep 
Set objOrun = QCutil.CurrentRun 
Set objSfact = objOrun.StepFactory 
Set att = objSfact.AddItem(null) 
att.name = aStepname 
att.post 
Set steplist = objSfact.NewList("SELECT * FROM Step 
WHERE 
ST_STEP_NAME='" & aStepname & "'") 
For each mystep in steplist 
        mystep.Status = aStatus 
        myStep.Field("ST_DESCRIPTION") = aDesc 
        myStep.Field("ST_EXPECTED") = aExpected 
        mystep.Field("ST_ACTUAL") = aActual 
        If mystep.Status = "Failed" then 
                objOrun.Status = "Failed" 
        end if 
        mystep.Post 
Next 
Set objSfact = Nothing 
Set objOrun = Nothing
```

Particularly, I cannot do this in Python -  mystep.Field("ST_ACTUAL") 
= aActual ; because I get the following error- 
"SyntaxError: can't assign to function call" 
Any help? 
Thanks, 
Amit

UPDATES:
Please, the python script can be found here...
[Adding testcase results to Quality Center Run from a outside Python Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773430/adding-testcase-results-to-quality-center-run-from-a-outside-python-script)

Comment: It would be tremendously useful to see the python code you've tried.

Comment: Please look at this link-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773430/adding-testcase-results-to-quality-center-run-from-a-outside-python-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer here: [Adding testcase results to Quality Center Run from a outside Python Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773430/adding-testcase-results-to-quality-center-run-from-a-outside-python-script)

Basically, instead of `mystep.Field("ST_ACTUAL") = aActual`, I can simply do this `mystep.SetField("ST_ACTUAL", "my actual result")`

Answer (score 2):

In Python `()` represent calls to functions, while `[]` represent indexing and mapping.

Comment: In other words, Python thinks you're trying to call a function, when what you're probably trying to do is index a collection.  In other words, use [] instead of ().

Comment: It doesn't work because, due to the COM interface of Python, 'Field' is treated as a method and we cannot use [] against a method.